# How to show/hide row inside foreach loop based on submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page where I need to show or hide the row based on the submit button. When the page loads I don't want to display the year. Years should display only when the submit button clicked. But with the below code only the first row is hidden on the page load. How to hide all the rows on page load?

```js
function showDiv() {
            var v = document.getElementById('search').value;
            document.getElementById('search').innerText = v;
            if (v) {
                document.getElementById("searchresult").style.visibility = "visible";

                document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("searchresult").style.visibility = "hidden";

                document.getElementById("hide").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
```

```html
    
    
   <button type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="showDiv()">Submit</button> 
   
  <div id="searchresult">
            <strong>You searched "<span id="search"></span>"</strong>
        </div> 
   
    @foreach (var groupMonth in Model.Records.GroupBy(recordLists => new { Lists.date.Value.Year, Lists.date.Value.Month }))
                    {
                        <tr >
                            <td colspan="4" style="font-weight:bold">
                                <div class="Header">
                                    <span id="hide" style="color: aqua;">@groupMonth.Key.Year</span> 
                                    
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `foreach` you are outputting multiple rows containing `<span id="hide"`. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. How is the code supposed to know which one you are talking about when you try to select by the ID? It can't, so it just chooses the first one it finds every time. All others are considered invalid. After all an ID - by definition - must be unique.

Instead of `id="hide"`, use `class="hide"` instead. And then you can select all the elements with that class, and hide them all.